# Как объединить такие элементы массива?

Tags: php

Задан массив такого формата:

```
$data = [
    [
        "NAME" => "asdasd",
        "FILE_ID" => 12,
        "COLOR" => "red",
        "PHONE" => "89998887744",
        "EMAIL" => "1@1.ru"
    ],
    [
        "NAME" => "asdasd",
        "FILE_ID" => 12,
        "COLOR" => "blue",
        "PHONE" => "89998887744",
        "EMAIL" => "1@1.ru"
    ],
    [
        "NAME" => "asdasd",
        "FILE_ID" => 12,
        "COLOR" => "yellow",
        "PHONE" => "89998887744",
        "EMAIL" => "2@2.ru"
    ],
];
```

Результатом должен быть один элемент массива который сгруппировал в массив значения элементов, которые отличны друг от друга.

Т.е. результат должен быть такой:

```
[
    "NAME" => "asdasd",
    "FILE_ID" => 12,
    "COLOR" => [
        "red",
        "blue",
        "yellow"
    ],
    "PHONE" => "89998887744",
    "EMAIL" => [
        "1@1.ru",
        "2@2.ru"
    ]
]
```

Какие есть элегантные варианты решения ? кроме решения в лоб: пробежаться в уикле, сравнивать элементы текущего и следующего элемента, если отличны, до добавить в массив.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В чистом(native) php, я не могу припомнить функцию, которая решала бы Вашу задачу. В этом случае, на мое мнение лучше использовать цикл(Производительность будет выше). Но можно попробовать использовать комбинацию: `array_map` + `array_column` + `array_unique` + `array_keys`.

```
<?php 
$data = [
    [
        "NAME" => "asdasd",
        "FILE_ID" => 12,
        "COLOR" => "red",
        "PHONE" => "89998887744",
        "EMAIL" => "1@1.ru"
    ],
    [
        "NAME" => "asdasd",
        "FILE_ID" => 12,
        "COLOR" => "blue",
        "PHONE" => "89998887744",
        "EMAIL" => "1@1.ru"
    ],
    [
        "NAME" => "asdasd",
        "FILE_ID" => 12,
        "COLOR" => "yellow",
        "PHONE" => "89998887744",
        "EMAIL" => "2@2.ru"
    ],
];

function group_array($data){
   return array_map(function($key) use ($data) {
      $result = array_unique(array_column($data, $key));
      if(sizeof($result) === 1) return $result[0];
      return $result;
  }, array_keys($data[0]));
}

var_dump(group_array($data));
```

Пример работы можно увидит [тут](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/939b8561be0b699af035421a261961583b5f858a)